# Separating celery consumer and producer

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I want my email service that I wrote to be completely decoupled from my flask application. I am using celery with rabbitmq. So I am wondering is there a way I can configure celery so that in one project I have the Flask application that sends the message to the queue (producer). And in another project I have the celery instance running that listens to the message and execute the task(consumer). I am still confused by how the communication will exactly work? Do I put the API (that sends the email) in my flask application OR the celery project? Ultimately I would like to have the Flask application and the Celery instance in different EC2 instances - with rabbitmq acting as the message broker.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Celery's [send_task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task) function to send the task through RabbitMQ to the worker using the task name. You still need to import the module that you have the celery app in:

> If the task is not registered in the current process you can use
>   send_task() to call the task by name instead.

Example:

```
from yourmodule.yourapp import celery
celery.send_task("yourtasksmodule.yourtask", args=["Hello World"])
```

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to do it without importing my module (as I am planning on putting it in a different server instance). As celery needs to be on both side of the pipe (rabbitmq), my question is - can I subclass from celery.Task - so that in one side I'll have methods that define what happens when a task is called (sends a message) and on the other do the actual tasks?

Comment: @user2216194
can you explain how did you got it working? I am stuck with the same problem as you

Comment: [Tutorial](https://moinulhossain.me/remote-celery-worker-for-flask-with-separate-code-base/) can help